# Link only answers with Stack Exchange content

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I just came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24868488/2291321) and was about to flag it as a link only answer but I then noticed that the link is to a Stack Exchange site.

As far as I'm aware Stack Exchange stuff is pretty constant and we're not likely to lose answers on one Stack Exchange site while the rest remain and URIs are stable. So does this rule still apply completely?

I've still commented on the answer and asked the OP to summarise the content of the link because it still makes sense to me to have the information directly in the answer rather than having to follow the link and then just leave the option to any reader to follow the link if they need more information.

Comment: If only we could mark questions as inter-site duplicates...

Comment: I actually thought you were being sarcastic then and tried to do just that. That would be pretty neat I guess.

Comment: Indeed. *Especially* for meta sites (no sarcasm here, the rampant content duplication since the MSE/MSO split makes me want to cry sometimes).

Comment: You *could* flag for migration to the site mentioned - however this would just create a duplicate on the target site.

Comment: So what needs to be done here? I figured it could actually be a valid question/answer for StackOverflow but the answer definitely needs more detail rather than just the link. Would other people instead recommend the question be closed? If the question is migrated and then closed then there's no evidence of it being asked on SO at all for the next time someone wants to do this and only looks on SO.

Comment: @ChrisF: But if the question is on-topic here, it probably will be re-asked and re-answered anyway. At least this way we have a duplication target, an anchor to the cross-site dupe...

Comment: @ydaetskcoR The question is ontopic on several SEs but this is not a valid close reason (yet), so you cannot close it. Giving more detail than just a link is a good idea anyway or you are free to downvote the answer. The principal question is what needs to be done with inter-site duplicates.

Comment: see also [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates)

Comment: @Trilarion so what you're saying is that this is a cross site duplicate of another question on meta.SE?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Yeah, I should have posted the link as answer plus a "hope that helps". But I'm not that mean. :)

Comment: The answer has been deleted by the community.